Python Polars SQL Interface asof Join
Is there a SQL interface equivalent for the asof join in polars? I use by and on arguments often with these joins.
The methodology that I am using in the meantime is the one provided for Snowflake before the asof join was introduced in the SQL interface: How to do an as-of-join in SQL (Snowflake)?
I've spent a few minutes looking through GitHub and the closest issue I saw raised was this issue. However this does not strictly deal with the SQL interface or asof joins. Thanks.

join_asof() exists in polars, but if you need inequality joins, then I'll suggest you look into DuckDB and its integration with Polars.
Regarding SQL interface to polars - I'd say it's in its infancy still.

Thanks @RomanPekar, I have been using the join_asof, but just looking to write purely in the SQL interface. Thanks, will look into the DuckDB integration.

There doesn't seem to be any match for asof in polars-sql https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Apola-rs%2Fpolars+path%3A%2F%5Ecrates%5C%2Fpolars-sql%5C%2F%2F+asof&type=code - you'll probably have to open a feature request.

there's duckdb asof join which is more elegant than usual "window function" approach.
One thing to remember is duckdb on polars works in eager mode.
